# Existe alguma ferramenta para desktop ou mobile que informe que há analise no site a ser feita?

Tags: suporte, novo-recurso

Sei que o StackOverflow tem uma API onde podemos desenvolver algumas soluções, porém agora não posso me comprometer a desenvolver tal solução se ela não existe ainda.

Gostaria de saber se há uma ferramenta que informe no desktop (como ocorre no chat quando somos citados) ou para celular/Tablet/iPad (Mobile) que há analises a serem feitas no site.

Com base no debate desta questão, o @bfavaretto citou a limitação da [API do StackExchange](http://api.stackexchange.com) para este recurso, como poderia sugerir tal recurso?

Comment: Não que eu saiba, nem achei nada no http://stackapps.com. Mas talvez o Guilherme Nascimento desenvolva algo :D

Comment: Seria interessante algo que fosse multiplataforma e que fosse agregado a barra de tarefas do sistema operacional, e não condicionado a estar com o navegador aberto.
Uma vez eu desenvolvi um mecanismo de alerta em java com Swing para um sistema de Tickets feito em PHP.

Caso o @GuilhermeNascimento se interesse em usar o Java, é só abrir o projeto no GitHub e me mandar o convite, que vamos trabalhando juntos.

Comment: @bfavaretto esta seria a mais próxima [StackApplet](http://stackapps.com/questions/83/stackapplet-bringing-stack-exchange-notifications-to-your-desktop-large-scale), pena que é em Python, estou bastante enferrujado e garrado do jeito que estou com o Spring Security e agregados, nem pensar em assumir algo extra fora do java.

Comment: [A API](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs) não deve ajudar muito, só tem métodos para buscar edições sugeridas, e mais nada ligado a análises (*reviews*).

Comment: Realmente, dá para fazer uma analise básica das novas questões, e das não respondidas, é um inicio, como poderia ser proposta esta expansão da API? (vou adicionar isso a pergunta)

Comment: Acho que abrindo um pedido de novo recurso, aqui mesmo ou no [meta.se] (em inglês).

Comment: Eu acho que isso não existe por conta do número de análise estar em constante mudança, é difícil contabilizar quantas existem porque isso ocorre muito rápido por aqui — *eu acho*. Quer ver um exemplo? Quem nunca recebeu uma notificação de que haviam *propostas de edições* pendentes e, ao acessar a página de análise elas já tinham sido atendidas por outros usuários!? Até fazer a *requisição e checagem, verificar se há análises pendentes, notificar o usuário (se existir), ele acessar o site*... já foi o tempo daquele número de análises apresentado na notificação ter mudado.

Comment: Eu ainda não comecei a estudar a API, mas se ela der suporte (não sei se existe suporte pra isto), provavelmente terá que configurar apenas um comunidade (na primeira versão) pra visualizar as notificações. Apesar de ter algum conhecimento em java, a extensão do navegador pode usar notificações (html5) mesmo em background. Mas se o que você acha melhor é um widget fixo no Desktop então teremos que partir pro java mesmo ( ou pro C++ :) ). Poderia sugerir uma interface?

Comment: Concordo com você @re22, porém a ferramenta pode trazer uma abertura para um segundo desenvolvimento como um bot que analisa em mais detalhes as postagens, e faz comentários por exemplo (isso é permitido?), isso seria um segundo passo claro depois do widget funcional em sua ação primária. Sobre o fato de se visitar a página ver o alerta, e corrigir, há um lag para o sistema muito alto devido aos intervalos de visitação, com o widget isso seria bem mais rápido, e não dependeria tanto de sorte.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento, interface a nível de usuário não é meu forte. 
Sobre a [API](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs), visite este link e não achei nada especializado.

Comment: Até que se desenvolva algo similar, vou deixar o link da ferramenta desenvolvida pelo @GuilhermeNascimento http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/4075/8039 de uma opção bem interessante que estendida poderia atender tal proposta.

Comment: @Delfino Eu achei que você já tinha visto a ferramenta que ele fez, eu brinquei que ele faria justamente por causa disso :)

Comment: Agora que li o comentário do @re22, parece que é inviável no momento mesmo :(